# Flipping the pose on the x axis is pasted incorrectly

Tags: armature, mirror, pose-mode, axis

So for the past few hours i have been trying to animate a simple walk cycle but couldn't because
when i try to flip the pose on the x axis it doesn't paste it correctly. ([Blend File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ImLxmdZQSZpc6-L85rG21IYxk5ocJP3r))

The pose i copied:

[image: The pose i wanted to flip on the x axis]

And this is the pose i got when i fliped it on the x axis:

[image]

- Both pictures are viewed in the same angle .
- I checked the armature names in case it didn't fit the naming convention but there's nothing
  wrong with it .
- I complitely redone the rigging multiple times just to be sure but it didn't change anything.
- Everything other then the legs are pasted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bones of your right leg are not well oriented, you must have duplicated your left leg instead of symmetrized it. So delete the right leg, bend a bit the left leg (always better to show Blender in what direction it is supposed to bend), symmetrize it. As you'll see you'll need to correct the *IK Pole Angle* of the right lower leg (0°). It should work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it finally worked!